# Why does screen.width detect different width than phone manufacturer stats?

Tags: javascript, media-queries

`Javascript` can detect the width and height of a device's screen using `screen.width` and `screen.height`.

For example this simple code returns screen width and height to the console:

```js
var screenSizeX = screen.width;
var screenSizeY = screen.height;

console.log("Screen width is " +screenSizeX);
console.log("Screen height is " +screenSizeY);
```

Knowing the correct width and height of popular device screens goes a long way towards determining how `Media Queries` organize `CSS`.  However there are huge discrepancies between what `Javascript` detects and what manufacturers report in sales literature.

**Example 1:** On a Samsung S7 Edge `Javascript` returns a width of 640px and a height of 360px.  However according to the manufacturer the width is 2560px and the height is 1440px with 534 pixels per inch.

**Example 2:** On an IPhone 7+ `Javascript` returns a width of 736px and a height of 414px. However according to Apple the width is 1920px and the height is 1080px with 401 pixels per inch.

Without owning a device and checking with `Javascript` this makes the true screen width and height of a device a mystery.

Why does `Javascript` return such a vastly different number compared to manufacturer stats?  Is there a mathematical or code based way to rectify these discrepancies?